# maven 3.8.0 :testCompile (default-testCompile) on project App: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, java-11

I am using jdk 11 with maven 3.8.0. please find below given pom.xml. i am getting error

> Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>7.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

getting error

```
Aug 1 15:50:11  [WARNING] The requested profile "inttest" could not be activated because it does not exist.
Aug 1 15:50:11  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project some-service: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
Aug 1 15:50:11  [ERROR] 
Aug 1 15:50:11  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Aug 1 15:50:11  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Aug 1 15:50:11 [ERROR] 
Aug 1 15:50:11  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Aug 1 15:50:11  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Did you set your project with java 11 and $JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: First I recommend to use the most recent version of maven-compiler-plugin (3.8.1) furthermore the invalid flags implies you are not using JDK 11 for building or not correctly set JAVA_HOME as already stated...no dependency to asm is needed...

Comment: @khmarbaise problem solved thanks

Answer (score 2):

This error usually happens when you use `<release>11</release>` command line feature of Java 9, but build it with Java 8.

`mvn --version`

Should give you

````
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /home/.../.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.7-open
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.10-200.fc32.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"   ```
````